# Find if the first 8 characters of previous line in excel matches the first 8 characters of current line

Tags: c#, list, matching

I have put all my lines from my excel file into a list. I am trying to match all of the lines that have the same IDs to each other and put them in list.  I am not sure how to go about doing it.

```
//make list a string
for(int i= 1; i <listCount; i++)
{
    mytextfrompdf = myStringList.ToString();
}

//find the matching IDs throughout the list
foreach (string textLine in myStringList)
{   
    //Get the first 8 characters of the string (ID numbers)
    string aNumber = textLine.Substring(0,8);

    //Does ID match the previous ID?
    if (aNumber.LastIndexOf())
    {
       //if  IDs match add to existing list

    }
    else //create a new list                 
}
```

Comment: The same IDs as what? Is there a 2nd list apart from the one you created from the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

This is could be a nice comparison algorithm if i got you right:

```
        List<string>myStringList= new List<string>();
          string prevID= myStringList.First().Substring(0,8);
        foreach (string textLine in myStringList)
        {
            //Get the first 8 characters of the string (ID numbers)
            string aNumber = textLine.Substring(0, 8);

            if (aNumber.Equals(prevID))

            {

                //do whatever you want with them.
            }

            else
            {


            }
            prevID= aNumber ;
        }
```

Good enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the strings by their first 8 characters with LINQ:

```
List<List<string>> result = stringList.GroupBy(textLine => textLine.Substring(0,8))
                                      .Select(g => g.ToList());
                                      .ToList();
```

This will give you a list of lists of strings.

Comment: When I typed in "List<List<string>> result = myStringList.GroupBy(textLine.Substring(0,8)).Select(g => g.ToList()); " I got the following error...
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not using lambda syntax, instead of `GroupBy(textLine.Substring(0,8))` it should be `GroupBy(textLine => textLine.Substring(0,8))`

Comment: Yes that worked! but now how do I access the groups? Like if I wanted to print to console?

Comment: Now you have a list of lists, so nested foreach will do - try `foreach (var list in result) { foreach (var str in list) Console.WriteLine(str); }`